# How to trouble-shoot install python-requests module

Tags: python, module, python-requests

Using `python3` On OSX I installed requests using `pip3 install requests`
When I run `>>>python -c "import requests"`, no errors, but when I run a file started with `import requests`, I get the following error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
  import requests
  ImportError: No module named 'requests'
```

Stumped.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I was running the file with python 2, but had installed requests under python 3(pip3).